# Is there a general FAQ/Wiki section for each tag where we can put useful functions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

I've got a list of date functions that I use pretty regularly in my Access apps; stuff like LastDayOfMonth, IsWeekend, DaysInMonth, etc...  General stuff that's definitely helpful if you work with dates at all.  I'm wondering if there is currently a place in the SE network where we can put these functions so other people can use them?  I've also got a few for C# (I'm still a n00b there but I use them a lot) as well that I'd be happy to dump somewhere if they'd be of use to others.

Comment: Be careful of asking questions that are easily answered with minimal knowledge/searching, even if you are answering them yourself for the purpose of sharing knowledge.  Seen people get downvoted/closed for trying to do a good deed. :/

Answer (score 6):

You can ask a question for which that information would be (part of) an answer, and then self-answer the question.

Having said that, good self answered questions are *hard*.  It's important that the question be of sufficient quality for the site.  It should be good enough that if you asked that question and didn't answer it yourself others would think it was a good question, well researched, follows all site guidelines, etc.  This is a lot of work, and many people struggle with it.

Because of the difficulty in asking *quality* self answered questions you may be better off just creating a blog or using some other external resource (there are lots of code sharing sites, if that's primarily what you want to share) that's better suited as a platform for you to simply share information that you would like to, without spending the considerable effort to force it into a Q/A model.

Answer (score 3):

> I've got a list of date functions that I use pretty regularly ... I'm wondering if there is currently a place in the SE network where we can put these functions so other people can use them?

I'd suggest forming them into a library, and releasing it as an open source project. Post it to GitHub or somewhere similar.

Comment: Was going to make a joke about a github repository for Access, but then I checked and saw there were a couple people with 'em.

Comment: @Won't: it's all code, right? Why not.

Comment: Because beat Access with a hockey stick until its a closed casket?

Comment: Hehe. Well, yes, there is that I guess  ;-)